# JWT token filter not working for spring security for mobile OTP based login

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, one-time-password

I am trying to implement SMS otp based login in spring boot application. I am not using username and password.
I am able to generate the JWT but subsequent request containing JWT in header is not letting me access resources with below error.

```
 {
        "timestamp": "2020-09-08T00:32:58.576+00:00",
        "status": 403,
        "error": "Forbidden",
        "message": "Access Denied",
        "path": "/hello"
}
```

My User class is below.
**User.class**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class User{
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String userName;
    private String phoneNumber;
}
```

I am using below jwt dependency

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
          <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
          <version>0.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is my JWT Token Filter.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.java.nikitchem.dao.UserDao;
import com.java.nikitchem.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.java.nikitchem.model.User;
import com.java.nikitchem.serviceImpl.TokenProvider;

@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String phoneNumber = null;
        String jwt = null;
        
        if(authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
            phoneNumber = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromToken(jwt);
        }
        
        if(phoneNumber!= null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            User user = null;
            try {
                user = userDao.getUserByPhone(phoneNumber);
                if(tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt, user)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null);
                    authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
                }
            } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.getMessage();
            }
            
            
            
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Below is my TokenProvider.class

**TokenProvider.class**

```
public class TokenProvider {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenProvider.class);

    private AuthConfig authConfig;

    public TokenProvider(AuthConfig authConfig) {
        this.authConfig = authConfig;
    }

    public String createTokenForUser(User user) {
        Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return generateToken(claims, user.getPhoneNumber());

    }

    private String generateToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String phoneNumber) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(phoneNumber).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 438)))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, authConfig.getTOKEN_SECRET()).compact();
    }
    
    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }
    
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(authConfig.getTOKEN_SECRET()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public String getUserIdFromToken(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(authConfig.getTOKEN_SECRET()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();

        return claims.getSubject();
    }
    
    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token,Claims::getExpiration);
    }
    
    public String extractUserId(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }
    
    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimResolver.apply(claims);
    }
    
    public boolean validateToken(String authToken, User user) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(authConfig.getTOKEN_SECRET()).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            final String phoneNumber = getUserIdFromToken(authToken);
            return (!isTokenExpired(authToken) && phoneNumber.equals(user.getPhoneNumber()));
        } catch (SignatureException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.class**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/auth", "/authenticate").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: can you share your exception's full stack trace?

Comment: I have few more question, have you verified using logging or printing in your token filter class, if you are getting the token and does your `TokenProvider` class injected (because it seems simple class not spring bean) ?, Also what are you doing when token is not valid or anything and please post complete stack trace of the error.

Comment: I am returning boolean value on token validation which will be processed and user will be redirected to Login page. And yes, **TokenProvider** is injected as Service.

Comment: @code_mechanic Its my personal project. here is the git URL.

https://github.com/aadizorro/Spring-Security-OTP

Comment: Ok the issue is solved.

I was trying to get a hold of UserDetails Object by passing password as null, which was breaking the Spring Security filterChain execution in JwtRequestFilter.

as a result, spring was giving  403 error.

Since, i am not working with password in USER class. I created UserDetails.User by passing empty string instead of null 

new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getPhoneNumber(),"", new ArrayList<>()); 


which solved the issue.

A very thanks to @code_mechanic for helping me out of this.

Answer (score 1):

In **JwtRequestFilter.class**,

```
if (phoneNumber != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(phoneNumber);
            if (tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails,
                        null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);

            }
            
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
```

I was trying to pass User object to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, which was breaking Spring Security FilterChain execution, giving 403 error.

After replacing User object to UserDetails.User object with empty string as password i.e.

```
new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getPhoneNumber(),"", new ArrayList<>());
```

(as i am not working with passwords in **User.class**)
and passing to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken for creating AuthenticationToken.

That worked perfectly fine.
Thanks to  [code_mechanic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712172/code-mechanic) for your help :)