# Spring Boot OTP (one time password) based login rest API?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on Spring boot REST API. It is a mobile application having two screens.

1. Enter phone / contact number (An OTP should be sent on this entered number)
2. Enter OTP to verify.

First part is done. Now, if a user enters OTP and otp gets verified, then user should get log in to system without entering password.

So, how should I get this thing done?

[image: Screenshot to display login screen]

Comment: You might want to start a bounty if you are actively looking for a solution.

Comment: Probably you can achieve this by using Twilio for OTP and jwt for authentication. A similar question is asked here as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791170/jwt-token-filter-not-working-for-spring-security-for-mobile-otp-based-login.

Comment: I have implemented a similar approach here. Feel free to check out, will update with doc in sometime https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/spring-boot-otp-login

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the OTP code, you should validate it and create a valid session token. Have a look on this example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationController.class);
    @Autowired
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    private OtpService otpService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping(value = "/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> authorize(@Valid @RequestBody LoginDTO loginDTO) {
        log.debug("Credentials: {}", loginDTO);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            loginDTO.getUsername(), loginDTO.getPassword());

        try {
            Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
            String token = tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, loginDTO.isRememberMe());
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new JWTToken(token), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException exception) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "verify")
    public ResponseEntity<JWTToken> verifyOtp(@Valid @RequestBody VerifyTokenRequestDTO verifyTokenRequest) {
        String username = verifyTokenRequest.getUsername();
        Integer otp = verifyTokenRequest.getOtp();
        Boolean rememberMe = verifyTokenRequest.getRememberMe();

        boolean isOtpValid = otpService.validateOTP(username, otp);
        if (!isOtpValid) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        String token = tokenProvider.createTokenAfterVerifiedOtp(username, rememberMe);
        JWTToken response = new JWTToken(token);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Full source:

https://github.com/hedza06/spring-boot-otp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/starter/springboot/auth/AuthenticationController.java

Answer (score 0):

You can be create jwt token in cache or cookie... Only userId be enough in JWT token.

```
if (tokenVerify(request.JWTtoken)) {
  int userId = decodeToken(request.JWTtoken).userId;
  User user = getUserById(userId);
  if (user.otp.verify(request.otp)) {
    user.login();
  }
}
```

I would go with a pseudocode design like this.